# Primefaces 4, Omnifaces 1.7 JSF handle session timeout fail

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces, wildfly

```
faces-config.xml

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>


web.xml

<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/Login/login.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<filter>
    <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.FacesExceptionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>facesExceptionFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

After a session timeout i want to be redirectet to the login page. I use Form based authentication. When i login wait one minute and then hit a button i often get the following page:

```
error page:
<partial-response id="j_id1">
 <redirect url="/CuViS/Manager/show.xhtml"/>
  <changes>
   <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">-2290296337409893276:-7107311277476366039</update>     
  </changes>
  </partial-response>
```

Where the url is the current page where i clicked the button.

When i remove the omnifaces configuration the same behavior appears. What I am doing wrong?